# RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0) When Using Google Maps Places API

Tags: flutter, api, google-places-api

I'm trying to search locations using google maps places API and I'm getting this error :

> RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Here is my code :

```
    final String url ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key=$key';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var placeId = json['candidates'][0]['place_id'] as String;

    return placeId;
  }
```

Comment: your response's `candidates` array is empty

Comment: @h8moss im using google places api for the array

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable Places API in Google cloud platforms..
otherwise it will throw you a denied request and your 'candidates' will come in as [], meaning nothing is being called..

Hope that helps.